# Garbage Collection in vfp9

Tags: visual-foxpro

When I close in memory cursors in Visual Foxpro 9, the memory is not always reduced. How can I go about releasing the cursor from memory so I can reduce the amount of memory my application uses

Comment: Kindly explain what you mean by in memory cursors in VFP. Cursors can be crated in memory instead of disk?  If so what would be command/option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VFP caches things to make execution faster. However, when it needs the memory for something else, it'll release older cached stuff.

If you want to override VFP's decisions, use SYS(1104). You may also want to play with SYS(3050) to tune VFP's memory allocation.